# Input fields single Quote turns to square when paste from word document

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, regex

I am facing an issue when i do copy paste from word document, single quote turns to square while storing in DB. It saves single quote when i type manually. The issue happens only copy paste from word. I am using regex String.fromCharCode(event.charCode).match(/[a-zA-Z ]/g). Do i need to modify anything here?

```
<input ng-disabled="type == 'cancel'" ng-focus="focused9 = true" ng-blur="focused9 = false" ng-hide="nextButtonClicked" onkeypress="return String.fromCharCode(event.charCode).match(/[a-zA-Z ]/g) != null" ng-model="Name" id="insName"  ng-model="direct.insName"  isalphabetic="true" isnumeric="false" isCharc ="false" class="inputFields" type="text"  placeholder=""/>
```

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Word uses “smart quotes” as opposed to “straight quotes”. Your code doesn’t know how to decode that character so you get a square instead. Check out this [article](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.windowscentral.com/change-smart-quotes-straight-quotes-microsoft-office-word-outlook-powerpoint%3famp) for how to disable “smart quotes”.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned Microsoft Word uses smart quotes (if enabled). It looks like your DB is not configured to store those characters in the appropriate encoding.

You may want to replace pasted smart quotes with straight quotes like that in JavaScript:

```js
const str = `“Those quotes are not so smart”`;

console.log(str.replace(/[\u2018\u2019]/g, "'")
           .replace(/[\u201C\u201D]/g, "\""));
```